# Email Attachment from directory is not always the latest using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments, mailto, scandir

**UPDATE #2 - FINAL ANSWER**
I figured and you'll see in the comments below that my comparison symbol needed to be changed. So I took the code in Update #1 and simply changed this:

```
return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
```

to:

```
return filemtime($a) > filemtime($b);
```

And that did it!!! Thanks everyone for the dialog.

**UPDATE**
I've updated my code. Now I'm getting the attachment sent but again, it's not grabbing the latest one. Here's my latest code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'php/PHPMailer2020/src/Exception.php';
require 'php/PHPMailer2020/src/PHPMailer.php';

$dir = "php/sketch-drawings/";
$pics = scandir($dir);

$files = glob($dir . "*.*");
usort($files, function($a, $b){
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

foreach ($files as $pics) {
    echo '<img src="'. $pics . '">';
}

// SEND EMAIL W/ ATTACHMENT OF LATEST IMAGE 
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Sender = "hello@myemail.com";
$mail->From     = "mail@myemail.com";
$mail->FromName = "My Company";
$mail->AddReplyTo( "mail@mycompany.com", "DO NOT REPLY" );
//$mail->AddAddress("info@mycompany.com");
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
$mail->isHTML(true);  
$mail->Subject  = "Latest Sketch Image";
$mail->Body     = "Latest Image Attached! \n\n Thanks - XYZ Digital.";
$mail->AddAttachment($pics);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Email Failed To Send.'; 
} 
else {
    echo 'Email Was Successfully Sent.'; 
    echo "</p>";
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Thanks! Message Sent")';
    echo '</script>';
}

$mail->ClearAddresses();
?>
```

**This issue:** 
The AddAttachment($filepath) returns an attachment, but it's not the most recent one-- I need it to always return the most recent image in the directory.

**Here's what I'm doing:**
I've created a web application that is basically a sketch pad. When a user taps on "Save" the code snaps a pic of the  element saves it to a directory and then sends an email to the pre-defined address with the snap of the canvas as an attachment... and the issue is above.

**What I've done:**
I've looked all over the place for a solve -- seems as though the only find is around uploading the attachments via a web form--which isn't my issue. My workflow is different and why I'm here asking now. :)

**What's not working:**
Everything works except for the attachment part. I'm using PHPMailer but for some reason, the attachment is never the latest one. In fact, it seems to always be the same attachment no matter what.

I tried to get the first element in the array doing this (which I echo in the bottom of the code and it returns the right image:

```
$mail->addAttachment($sketches[0]);
```

this doesn't work -- it sends the email, but nothing attached.

How in the world, can I adjust my code below to get the latest attachment? I appreciate any help as PHP is not my area of expertise.

See the code below...

```
<?php // NEW
// DEFINE ERRORS 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer2020/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer2020/src/PHPMailer.php';

// GET LATEST UPLOAD -- AND HAVE IT STORED IN DOM (WHEN NEEDED) 
$path = ('sketch-drawings'); 

// Sort in descending order
$sketches = scandir($path, 1);

$latest_ctime = 1;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
    // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
    if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
        $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
        $latest_filename = $entry;  
    }

    // SEND EMAIL W/ ATTACHMENT OF LATEST IMAGE 
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->Sender = "hello@myemail.com";
    $mail->From     = "mail@myemail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "My Company";
    $mail->AddReplyTo( "mail@myemail.com", "DO NOT REPLY" );
    //$mail->AddAddress("info@myemail.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
    $mail->isHTML(true);  
    $mail->Subject  = "Latest Sketch Image";
    $mail->Body     = "Latest Image Attached! \n\n Thanks - XYZ Digital.";
    $mail->AddAttachment($filepath);
    //$mail->addAttachment($sketches);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Email Failed To Send.'; 
    } else {
        echo $filepath;
        echo "<br><br>";
        print $latest_filename;
        echo "</p>";    
        echo "<p>";
        print $sketches[0];
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo 'Email Was Successfully Sent.'; 
        echo "</p>";
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Thanks! Message Sent")';
        echo '</script>';
    }

    $mail1->ClearAddresses();
}

?>
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear why there are many unused code in your question. Did you mean `$mail->AddAttachment($d);` because I think $d is the right folder (name sketch-drawings)

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, the AddAttachment($filepath) returns an attachment, but it's never the most recent one. That's the issue. (Also, I've updated my OP).

I also tried ($d) but that returns a PHP fatal error from phpMailer script.

Comment: Debug one thing at a time; make sure the selection of the file is working *before* you try using it in the email. For example copy it somewhere else, rename it, display the full path. Don’t assume what’s in your variables - **check**!

Comment: Ah.. just realized my pasted code was not matching -- I was trying new variables-- trying to see what would echo. I updated OP again.

Comment: I think my issue is where I define what $filepath is -- although, I'm not sure how to tell $filepath to equal the first array of $sketches..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `dir()` function returns items in an [indeterminate order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php#refsect1-function.dir-notes). If you want to retrieve files ordered by date, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899810/php-scandir-sorting-by-file-date/28900147).

Comment: Awesome. Let me work through this and I'll report back! thanks for the comment

Comment: Hmmm. This is doing the same thing -- it's not grabbing the latest file. I've updated the code

Comment: ok, looks like it's returning the first image vs, the last. I tried to update my scandir to $pics = scandir($dir, 1); but that doesn't seem to change it.

Comment: Your comparison function is wrong. It must return an integer representing which of the two arguments is larger. To sort in reverse order, try this: `return ( filemtime($a) > filemtime($b) ) ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: OK!!! the full on code you suggested wasn't working -- so piece by piece I kept looking and realized, what if I just change the comparison symbol... Walla! That got it..... I just changed the < to > and we're firing on all cylinders! Thanks again for the back and forth!